# Windows Forms application remains alive in task manager after hitting "stop debugging" button

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, visual-studio-2012, process

I'm developing an application in C#, it uses WinForms and some unmanaged code too (PInvoke calls to native C++ DLL).

After stopping debugging via stop button in VS 2012, the main executable (not vshost.exe) still remains in windows task manager, and is idle consuming about 110-120 kBytes of memory.

Moreover after killing this process via task manager, I must also restart VS 2012 because some dialog windows tells mi that IDE is unable to start debugging.

Additionally, maybe it will be useful information (I'm unsure) but sometimes when I hit pause, IDE turns in to debug mode, but only for 3-4s, and after that VS2012 freezes, but my application starts to running...

I've installed VS 2012 Update 4 but it not helps.

How to avoid this issue?

Comment: What kind of operations does the unmanaged code perform?

Comment: It uses Direct3D9 mainly. I'm exchanging also some structures via marshalling.

Comment: My guess is that there is some issue with those native operations. DirectX for example tends to have such phenomena, especially if you're in the middle of a scene rendering etc.  . In addition dealing with threads in native code also may have similar phenomenon. Can you try to see if this happens when using the same native DLL from pure native application?